# I can't see my loader twice

Tags: angular

I’m using `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` to paginate, and `ngx-loading` to display a loader:

They both work great.

Pagination:

```
{{ loading }}
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="tournaments?.meta?.total"
            [(page)]="page" aria-label="Default pagination"
            [pageSize]="tournaments?.meta?.per_page"
            [maxSize]="5"
            [rotate]="true"
            (clic)="loading=true"
            (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"
            size="lg"
            class="d-flex justify-content-center"></ngb-pagination>
```

and the second in my container

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
```

Thing is when I change page, and refresh the data, loader is not appearing.

I can see `loading` variable changing from false to true when I click a pagination link, but the loader is not showing.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is a typo: `(clic)`. Not sure if that changes anything though

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by typo ???

Comment: I assume you want to call the function on the `(click)` event. The `(clic)` probably does not do anything.

Comment: Yes you are right, but weirdly, it was also working with (clic).

Comment: I changed it and I still can't see the loader

Comment: I can't really see an obvious error. But what I would probably do is put the `this.loading = true;` into the `pageChanged` function.

Comment: I already done that. it doens't work. I extracted it in the page so it would not depend on when the pageChanged is called

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding a *ngIf condition on the main container:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="!loading">
...
</div>
```

Also with that condition, I get rid of all error message in console that say that my object are not defined.